# Setting multiple parameters on breakpoint in MUI v5

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

In MUI v4 I was able to set multiple style parameters on a single media query using something like the following:

```
 [theme.breakpoints.up('xs')]: {
      width: 100px,
      color: green,
    },
 [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: 400px,
      color: blue,
    },
```

In MUI v5, I can set them individually on a component with the `sx` prop, in a relatively convenient way:

```
...
sx={{
  width: {xs:'100px', md:'400px'},
  color: {xs: 'green', md:'blue'}
}}
```

However I would like to be able to achieve the same type of functionality as in v4, where multiple params can be adjusted under a single breakpoint. It seems like the control has been inverted, and while this is often useful, I'd like to be able to use the original version as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way.

Using the callback functionality it is possible to set it up just like in v4.

```
    <Box
      sx={[
        { // Add parameters that span all sizes
          display: 'flex',
          backgroundColor: {
            // Can also mix responsive parameters up here
            xs: 'yellow',
            md: 'purple'
        },

        // Add responsive parameters
        (theme) => ({
          [theme.breakpoints.between('xs', 'md')]: {
            color: 'blue',
            border: '2px solid red',
          },
          [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
            color: 'green',
            border: '2px solid purple',
          },
        }),
      ]}
    >
```

Answer (score 2):

This seem to work for me.

```
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

...

```
function MyComponent() {
  const theme = useTheme();
```

...

```
sx={{
 [theme.breakpoints.up('xs')]: {
      width: 100px,
      color: green,
    },
 [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: 400px,
      color: blue,
    },
}}
```